# Having issues mounting a SMB drive and reading it without root

Tags: macos

I am trying to mount a SMB drive and have it readable by users, not root/sudo.

The drive mounts but cannot be accessed by users, even when the permissions clearly say it should be.

I've tried mounting the drive with

```
sudo mount_smbfs -d 755 -f 755 //[user]@[ip]/NAS NAS
```

Then I try to cd NAS and it says permission denied.

Weird part is when I try:

```
$ sudo ls -lah
$ drwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    16K Jul 21 00:53 NAS
```

So.. this makes no sense from my perspective.. why can't I access the share?

I can read it just fine with sudo but cannot with my normal user.

Comment: Your issue is right there — the owner is `root`, so unless those users trying to access the NAS are part of the `wheel` group then of course it's going to be permission denied.

Comment: sorry but i disagree based on this: drwxr-xr-x. that last r-x should let anyone read it at least,- also, even if that is the case how do i fix it? chown doesnt work on mounts nor do the -u or -U flags with the mount_smbfs command

Comment: There's more to it than that; what is the output of `ls -lOe /`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WiETdeJ

Comment: Try it with `ls -lOe /Volumes/NAS`, or just `ls -lOe /Volumes`...

Comment: had to sudo but -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  hidden 10244 Sep  1 20:13 .DS_Store
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  hidden  4096 Jul 21 00:53 ._.DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  hidden 16384 Jul 12 22:37 .recycle
drwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  -      16384 Apr 13 10:40 Folder

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  - 16384 Jul 21 00:53 NAS

Comment: Why is your NAS set to have root owner in the first place?

Comment: hmm like on the mounted folder? it was set like that to begin with as soon as,i mounted it. no idea how to change it

Comment: ok seems as long as i run the mount_smbfs command without sudo it'll work, odd but thanks! i'll just mount it to a non /Volumes location

Comment: I would recommend setting the permissions to your username account and group. Generally anything that has root permission is stuff you don't want to have easy access to (unless you have zero security concerns).

Answer (score 0):

seems as long as i run the mount_smbfs command without sudo it'll work, odd but thanks! i'll just mount it to a non /Volumes location